# What are the requirements for purchasing a house in Amber Creek?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-falskaar

I was trying to purchase a house in Amber Creek. I talked to Jalma about this, but was told that they "don't know me well enough to allow that".

Aside from the 10K gold, what are the other prerequisites (i.e. which quests and how many quests do I need to finish) for buying a house in Amber Creek?

[image: screenshot]

<sup>*"I'm sorry, but we don't know you well enough to allow that. With how many bandits and thugs there are right now, we have to be careful."*</sup>

Comment: @One-One The [tag:skyrim-falskaar] tag has been made a synonym of the [tag:falskaar] tag, so questions tagged with either will end up with the [tag:falskaar] tag.

Comment: @One-One About the tagging, I just asked about it in meta: [How should questions about Falskaar (Skyrim mod) be tagged?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7442/4797)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to Alexander J. Velicky (Falskaar mod author)](http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1469226-rel-falskaar-thread-3/page-6#entry23132126), apart from the 10K gold...

> Completing any 3 quests for the folk in town allows you to purchase the house.

Answer (score 1):

Just do the mini quests to help the residents in Amber Creek. 
I personally helped the Guy at the sawmill and the woman in the shop and was able to purchase the home.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, apart from the 10K gold, you need to do some little quests by helping people in Amber Creek. Two at least, and then they will know you.